# Matplotlib PyPlot Lines in Histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm a beginner to matplotlib's pyplot and was wondering how to get black lines between the bars of the histogram. I did some googling and [others were seeming to get this behavior](https://pythonspot.com/en/matplotlib-histogram/) out of the box with the same commands as I was using.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `matplotlib` version 2, transparent edges in histograms became the default([Reference](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc2/users/dflt_style_changes.html#patch-edges-and-color)), to modify that just add the `edgecolor = 'black'` parameter to your `plt.hist`:

```
plt.hist(data, 20, alpha=.5, edgecolor = 'black')
```

---

Demo with random data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)
plt.hist(x, 20, alpha=0.5, edgecolor = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image]